# Animation in Silverlight/XNA

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, animation, xna

I've been practicing with the new Silverlight/XNA model but I'm not sure how to go about animating a game character. Anyone know the best approach to animating in Silverlight/XNA? Would I still use XNA frame-based animation? (I tried this and I was unsure on how to get elapsed time from GameTimer where as GameTime had it as a property)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example for Frame Based Sprite Animation in Silverlight

http://www.bluerosegames.com/silverlight-games-101/post/Frame-Based-Sprite-Animation-in-Silverlight.aspx

Comment: I used frame based sprite animation and it seemed to work alright I just wasn't sure on what was best.

Comment: Cool, I also started a silverlight based game yesterday, my strategy is a mix of both frame-based and storyboard-based approaches. Good luck